# R: remove bidirectional hits from table

Tags: r, performance

I have the following table which contains some bidirectional hits in V1 and V2 for each unique V1. I want to remove one of each bidrectional hit (random choice)

```
V1 V2 V3
1  T  Y
1  Y  T
1  O  P
2  Q  E
2  E  Q
2  C  V
2  V  C
2  Y  T
```

the result table should be like this:

```
V1 V2 V3
1  T  Y
1  O  P
2  E  Q
2  V  C
2  Y  T
```

this can be done using a for loop, but i need a more efficient way.

what is the fastest way to do this in R?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Is the "random" choice important or does it mean that it doesn't matter which one of the bidirectional hits you choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that *random choice* means that it does not matter which bidirectional hit we choose:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("V1 V2 V3
1  T  Y
1  Y  T
1  O  P
2  Q  E
2  E  Q
2  C  V
2  V  C
2  Y  T"), header=TRUE)

rows1 <- apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse="")
## swap the order of column 2,3
rows2 <- apply(df[, c(1, 3:2)], 1, paste0, collapse="")

rows <- rbind(rows1, rows2)
rows
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
# rows1 "1TY" "1YT" "1OP" "2QE" "2EQ" "2CV" "2VC" "2YT"
# rows2 "1YT" "1TY" "1PO" "2EQ" "2QE" "2VC" "2CV" "2TY"

vrows <- as.vector(rows)
vrows
# [1] "1TY" "1YT" "1YT" "1TY" "1OP" "1PO" "2QE" "2EQ"
# [9] "2EQ" "2QE" "2CV" "2VC" "2VC" "2CV" "2YT" "2TY"

iunique <- which(!duplicated(vrows))
iunique
#  [1]  1  2  5  6  7  8 11 12 15 16

## because of the rbind above we have need only every second entry and 
## divide it by 2
i <- iunique[seq(2, length(iunqiue), by=2)]/2

df[i, ]
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  T  Y
# 3  1  O  P
# 4  2  Q  E
# 6  2  C  V
# 8  2  Y  T
```

Comment: I remember seeing a similar question the other day. There was suggested to sort the values before pasting. I think that would also simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's fastest (will depend on the number of duplicates,etc), but you can join two copies of the data together, and then drop duplicates (middle line is to randomise the row-order, so the chosen one is truly random):

```
mirrored <- rbind (dframe, dframe[,c(1,3,2)])
mirrored <- mirrored[sample(nrow(mirrored)),]
dedup <- mirrored[!duplicated(mirrored),]
```

Comment: Hi, this seems not to work, at the end the dedup contain the same data frame as the original one